# How to preserve text formation when converting to text to pdf?

Tags: java, pdf, text

I am having some problems with converting a text file to pdf. Actually converting is fine, I am using iText. The problem is that the structure of the text changes in pdf. My text file contains something like this:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
DATE     DESCRIPTION             REFERENCE        OTHER DATE                DEBIT               CREDIT              BALANCE       
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
07/06/10    WITHDRAWAL         8734589238549535   07/06/12             469,000.00                              2,000,448.95
```

When I convert it to pdf I get it not any more structured. I guess it is because "-" and white spaces " " have different sizes in pdf and text file. 
I need to preserve the original format and convert it to pdf (or image maybe).
Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should choose a [monospace font](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font). This will ensure that all characters have the same width.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I am using com.itextpdf.text.Font and it has no monospace font. Any suggestion?

Comment: Sorry it works very well :D For iText I followed this: http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=208    Thank you!